# Keras categorical crossentropy learning stuck by putting all in one category

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I was following the [tensorflow tutorial on classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) but got stuck with the problem, that the learning stagnates with my trained network in a sub optimal solution putting all pictures in just one categorie. My first thought was, that this was due to an unballanced distribution of training pictures in the categories ([as also suggested here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/what_can_cause_neural_network_to_classify_everything_to_single_class)), so I deleted enough training pictures, so that the same amount of pictures remained in each category. However, the problem did not change. Next I tried different loss functions, different metrics, different optimizers and different layer structures of my model, without any improvements. My model still puts all pictures in just one category after training. Any idea is highly welcome.

Here is one of the models I tried:

```
        model = keras.Sequential([
            keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(PicHeight, PicWidth, 3)),
            keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(number_of_categories, activation='softmax')
        ])
        model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And this is the training

```
Train on 101 samples
Epoch 1/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 11ms/sample - loss: 55.8119 - accuracy: 0.1584
Epoch 2/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/sample - loss: 232.9768 - accuracy: 0.1485
Epoch 3/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/sample - loss: 111.9690 - accuracy: 0.1584
Epoch 4/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/sample - loss: 72.1569 - accuracy: 0.1782
Epoch 5/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/sample - loss: 39.3051 - accuracy: 0.1386
Epoch 6/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/sample - loss: 2.6347 - accuracy: 0.0990
Epoch 7/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/sample - loss: 2.3318 - accuracy: 0.1683
Epoch 8/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/sample - loss: 2.5922 - accuracy: 0.2277
Epoch 9/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/sample - loss: 2.0848 - accuracy: 0.1485
Epoch 10/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/sample - loss: 1.9453 - accuracy: 0.1386
Epoch 11/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/sample - loss: 1.9453 - accuracy: 0.1386
Epoch 12/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/sample - loss: 1.9453 - accuracy: 0.1386
Epoch 13/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/sample - loss: 1.9452 - accuracy: 0.1386
Epoch 14/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/sample - loss: 1.9452 - accuracy: 0.1485
Epoch 15/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/sample - loss: 1.9452 - accuracy: 0.1485
Epoch 16/16
101/101 [==============================] - 1s 7ms/sample - loss: 1.9451 - accuracy: 0.1485
25/25 - 0s - loss: 1.9494 - accuracy: 0.1200
```

The training data has 7 categories with 18 pictures each.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use so many FC layers. They aren't really good in dealing with pictures.
2. Your dataset size is obviously too small for deep learning. Adding more training data or try traditional machine learning like SVM, LR.

Imbalanced training data won't have that effect on model performance. It really depends on how imbalanced your data are. If it is less than 15%, it will be fine. You can definitely improve by weighted loss, overbalancing, preprocessing to make more images,etc.

If you have enough training data and picture sizes are bigger than 20*20, you should try CNN.